# How to move file or directories in linux

Tags: linux

HELP. I need help with moving directories and files in Linux because i don't understand how to it and how it works, i am a student in year 11 so if someone could explain in the most simplest way possible or in a step by step guide would be helpful Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

It's mv

```bash
mv directoryName newLocation/directoryName
```

More info here http://linoxide.com/linux-command/mv-command-linux/

Comment: That assumes you're using the command line, not a graphical interface.

Comment: I generally assumed op wasn't asking me how to drag and drop. But yes, this is command line.

Comment: Well, he's asking for a "step by step guide" and posted his question to the wrong site, so I'm careful with my assumptions.

Comment: @melpomene That's fair. :)

Comment: Thanks for the help :)